# Is there a complex equivalent of the convolution product?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, convolution

For two continuous real-valued functions $(f,g),$ the convolution product is defined as

$$h(t)=(f*g) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(\lambda )g(t-\lambda ) \, d\lambda $$

So for two complex valued functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ the convolution product would look something like:

$$h(z)=(f*g)=\int_{z\in \Gamma} f(\omega)g(z-\omega) \, d\omega$$

where $\Gamma$ is a closed contour containing singularities. Now if $f$ and $g$ are entire functions then $h(z) = 0$ so this would only be useful for meromorphic functions with isolated singularities.

Comment: What do you mean by $dw$ here?  If it is the usual $dw$ in complex analysis then you can't integrate it on a 2-dimensional surface.  If it is the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure then the integral doesn't exist for most entire $f,g$ (e.g., $f=g=1$ and you are integrating the constant function 1 on against an infinite measure).  If you just treat $\mathbb{C}$ as an (locally compact ...) group with a Haar measure $dw$ then you are only using $\mathbb{R}^2$ and you probably want to restrict $f,g$ to $C_c$, $L^1$ or something like that for the convolution product.

Comment: Look up Hadamard convolution as it is what you want

Comment: you can define convolutions as integration along curves.  If the functions you are convolving contain singularities, some paths will produce different results.

Comment: @user10354138 sorry I made a mistake in the initial post. I meant to refer to contour integration.